# printing HTML document embedded in an object tag

Tags: html, printing, object-tag

i have a HTML document which is embedded in an 'object' tag.

```
<object data="scroll.html" type="text/html" width="100%" style="height:2700px;"/>
```

This HTML document spans across several pages. When i try to print the document in Firefox or IE9 , they only print the first visible page in the HTML and not all the pages. Am i missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make also the height

```
   height="50%"  // just a try of 50 u can use how much u like
```

EDIT:

```
   <object data="scroll.html" type="text/html" width="732" height="95" style="overflow:hidden; width: 732px; height: 2700px""/>
```

you are already using style , so dont use again style=....

Comment: Did not help, it printed only a part of the first page.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it still prints only the first page in FF and IE9. I forgot to mention in my question that it works in chrome.

Comment: I do not have a link, its a simple HTML document which has an object tag. The file 'scroll.html' spans across multiple pages. Let me know if you want me to send the file.